# Is there a non-negative integer x that is not a palindrome but for which x == reverse_digits(x) due to an overflow?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, binary, palindrome

I recently started solving some problems on LeetCode where I came across a [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-number/) that asks to write a function that checks whether a non-negative integer `x` is a palindrome, i.e. whether `x` reads the same backwards as forwards (e.g. `121`, `1221`, `91919`).

One approach to check whether a number is a palindrome is to reverse its digits and compare whether the two numbers are the same. For that, assume that we have the following implementation of a `reverse_digits` function:

```
int reverse_digits(int x) {
    int acc = 0;
    while (x != 0) {
        acc = acc * 10 + x % 10;
        x = x / 10;  // integer division, rounds down
    }
    return acc;
}
```

However, if we use a programming language in which the `int` type has a fixed width, then this function is prone to overflows. If we assume, for example, that an `int` has 32 bits, then, using the above implementation, we get:

```
reverse_digits(1_000_000_001) -> 1_000_000_001 # correctly reversed
reverse_digits(1_000_000_009) -> 410_065_409   # incorrect
```

**My question is**:

For the given implementation of `reverse_digits` and a given number of bits in the `int` type, is there a non-negative integer `x` that is *not* a palindrome but for which `x == reverse_digits(x)` (due to the overflow caused by the finite number of bits)? We assume that `x` does not have any leading zeros.

I manually checked the 4-bit case and I wrote a small program in C that checks unsigned 32-bit integers by brute-force; in both cases, there is no such `x`. However, I am not sure how to prove that there is no such integer for the 64-bit case, or how to find one if there is.

**Observation 1:**

The largest unsigned 64-bit integer is `ULONG_MAX := 18_446_744_073_709_551_615` (with underscores added for readability) which starts with a `1` and has 20 digits. For an overflow to happen, `x` must have at least 20 digits and not end in zero. Otherwise, `reverse_digits` correctly reverses the number.
For `x` to have 20 digits, it must start with a `1`, as 20 digit numbers that start with a number greater than `1` don't fit into 64 bits.

**Observation 2:**

Let $(x_{1}x_{2} \dots x_{20})$ be the (decimal) digit representation of $x$, where $x_i$ is the digit at position $i$ of $x$. Since $x$ starts with $1$, we have $x_1 = 1$.

In the last iteration of the while-loop we calculate

$$(x_{20}x_{19} \dots x_{2})*10+x_1.$$
For an overflow to happen,

$$(x_{20}x_{19} \dots x_{2})*10+x_1 \gt \text{ULONG_MAX},$$

i.e. $(x_{20}x_{19} \dots x_{2}) \gt \text{1_844_674_407_370_955_161}$, i.e. the reverse of the last 19 digits of $x$ must be greater than that value.

**Observation 3:**

Let $y:=(x_{20}x_{19} \dots x_{2})$ be greater than $\text{1_844_674_407_370_955_161}$. It follows that $z:= y*10+1$ causes an overflow, which means that the binary representation of $z$ has more than 64 bits.

- Let $(a_1a_2 \dots a_{64})$ be the 64-bit binary representation of $(x_{1}x_{2} \dots x_{20})$.
- Let $(b_1b_2 \dots b_{64})$ be the 64-bit binary representation of $(x_{20}x_{19} \dots x_{2}) = y$.
- Let $(c_1c_2 \dots c_{64}c_{64+1} \dots c_{64+j})$ be the (64+j)-bit binary representation of $z$.

We know that

$$
(c_1 \dots c_{64+j}) = (b_1 \dots b_{64}) * 1010_2 + 1_2.
$$

We need find bits $a_i$ and $c_i$ such that

$$
(c_{1+j} \dots c_{64+j}) = (a_1a_2 \dots a_{64})
$$

or, alternatively, show that such bits cannot exist.

This is where I'm kind of stuck. My next step would be to figure out what values $j$ can take and then do the multiplication to try to find some relation between the $a_i$, $b_i$, and $c_i$. I'm not whether this is the right approach though.

Comment: What I don't know is, what happens to a number when it overflows? If $n$ is too big, what number do we get instead?

Comment: @GerryMyerson When a number overflows the left most bits just get cut off. For example, assume the width of an `int` is four bits and we want to reverse the number 15 which is `1111` in binary. 15 reversed is 51 which is `110011` in binary. Since we only have four bits, the left most two bits, i.e. `11`, just get dropped, so we end up with `0011` which is 3.

Comment: OK, so, you're asking if there's a number $n$, not a palindrome, such that the reversal of $n$, minus the high end bits, equals $n$. The mixture of bases ($n$ and its reversal in base *ten*, but the high end bits relating to the base *two* representation of the reversal of $n$) is going to make it difficult to write this as equations.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, that's my question! I'm not sure how the answer to it depends on the available number of bits, but I'm most interested in the 64 bit case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't wedded to base-two computers, then there are examples. Some are very silly; e.g., suppose your computer works in base $18$, and can only handle one digit numbers. Then consider the number $13$. It's not a palindrome. Its reversal is $31$, which, in base $18$, is $1(13)$ (one eighteen, plus thirteen ones). That overflows your one-digit computer, so it drops the overflow digit, and reports the reversal of $13$ to be $13$ – voila! a palindrome.

A less silly example is $1904$ in a base-three computer with seven-digit numbers.
$(1904)_{10}=(2121112)_3$.
$(4091)_{10}=(12121112)_3$.
The reversal causes overflow. Dropping the overflow digit leaves us with $(2121112)_3=(1904)_{10}$, so $1904$ gets reported as a palindrome. If seven digits seems a little small, I'm confident that bigger examples can be constructed for base-three computers.

For base two, here's an argument that this phenomenon can't happen. Let $b$ be the number of bits our machine can handle. Let $n$, our candidate palindrome, have $b$ bits when written in base two, so
$$
2^{b-1}\le n<2^b
$$
Let $n$ have $d+1$ digits when written in base ten, so
$$
10^d\le n<10^{d+1}
$$
Let's write $\tilde n$ for the (base ten) reversal of $n$. Then
$$
\tilde n-n<9\times10^d
$$
Also, $\tilde n-n$ is a multiple of nine. It consists of the overflow bits resulting from the reversal of $n$, so it's also a multiple of $2^b$. So
$$
\tilde n-n\ge9\times2^b
$$
These two inequalities give
$$
9\times2^b<9\times10^d
$$
so
$$
n<2^b<10^d\le n
$$
contradiction!

Comment: A beautiful proof and I learned something new, thank you very much! :-) 
I still got a question regarding the LHS of your first inequality: Why do we assume that $2^{b-1} \le n$? For example, in the 32 bit case, the number `1_000_000_009` only requires 30 bits when represented in binary but still overflows when it is reversed. I think you are not using this assumption in the rest of the proof, but I'm still wondering.

Comment: You need four bits of overflow to get a multiple of nine, and you can only get that much overflow if $n\ge2^{b-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

No, there is no 64 bit integer that satisfies the requirement:
$$ x \neq \text{actual_reverse}(x) \quad \text{and} \quad x = \text{reverse_digits}(x).$$

### Proof

Suppose that there is such a $x$. I will assume that $x$ itself lies below the overflow limit, i.e. $x < 2^{64}$.
Also, we can assume that $\text{actual_reverse}(x) > x$, otherwise no overflow will occur.
As you mentioned, $x$ will have 20 decimal digits.

First note that $\text{reverse_digits}(x) = \text{actual_reverse}(x) \bmod 2^{64}$.
For instance, in your own example: $\text{actual_reverse}(1000000009) = 9000000001 = 410065409 \bmod 2^{32}$ (this relation is true for all number of bits).

But, there is even a stronger relation, $\text{actual_reverse}(x)$ is not that much bigger than $2^{64}$, therefore, the $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ in the equation:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
\tag{1}
x = \text{reverse_digits}(x) = \text{actual_reverse}(x) - k \cdot 2^{64}
\end{equation}
is bounded by: $1 \leq k \leq \left \lfloor{{10^{20} / 2^{64}}}\right \rfloor = 5$.
This means that we only have to check if there exists a solution $x$ in \eqref{eq1} for each of the $5$ possible values of $k$.

So, how can we do that?
Write $x = (x_1 x_2 \dots x_{20})$ in base $10$, where $x_{20}$ is the least significant bit.
Similarly, fix a value of $k$ and write $k \cdot 2^{64} = (y_1 y_2 \dots y_{20})$ in base $10$.
Then we can rewrite \eqref{eq1} as:

\begin{equation}
\label{eq2}
\tag{2}
(x_1 + y_1) \cdot 10^{19} + (x_2 + y_2) \cdot 10^{18} + \dots + (x_{20} + y_{20}) = x_{20} \cdot 10^{19} + x_{19} \cdot 10^{18} + \dots + x_1.
\end{equation}

Now, we can't directly say that $x_1 + y_1 = x_{20}$, not even modulo $10$. This is because there can be a carry-over from the sum $x_2 + y_2$.
However, this carry-over is limited to $0$ or $1$ (since we are taking sums of integers, in products you can have much bigger carry-overs).

Hence, we get the following relation:
$$ x_1 + y_1 + j_1 = x_{20} \bmod 10 $$
where $j_1 \in \{0,1\}$.
Similarly, we find $x_{20} + y_{20} + j_{20} = x_1 \bmod 10$, where again $j_{20} \in \{0,1\}$. I guess $j_{20} = 1$ can be discarded, but anyways, combining these two equations gives:
$$ x_{20} + y_{20} + j_{20} + y_1 + j_1 = x_{20} \bmod 10. $$
Hence, $y_{20} + y_1 = k_1 \bmod 10$, where $k_1 \in \{ 0,9,8 \}$.
Note that this final relation only depends on the decimals of $k \cdot 2^{64}$!

We can now repeat this proces for the other digits in \eqref{eq2}. We find that for each $i = 0, 2, \dots, 19$:

$$ (y_i + y_{20-i} \bmod 10) \in \{ 0,9,8 \}. $$

It is very unlikely that there exists a $k$ such that the bits of $k \cdot 2^{64}$ satisfy all of these equations. Since, heuristically, the probability that one of them holds is $0.3$, hence the probability that all of them hold for at least one of the possible values of $k$ is $1 - (1 - 0.3^{20})^5 \approx 0$.
This is of course not a proof, that's why I checked the $5$ values of $k$ to see that they all don't work, see the Python code below.
The value for $k = 5$ came the furthest, since the first two equations held:
$$ 5 \cdot 2^{64} = 92233720368547758080 $$
and $9+0, 2+8 \bmod 10 \in \{ 0,9,8 \}$, but $2+0 \bmod 10 \not \in \{ 0,9,8 \}$.

As a side-note, we now see that if the number of bits is large, then the (heuristic) probability that a solution $x$ exists is very low. If the number of bits is smaller, then the probability is a bit better, but I bruteforced everything for 20 digits or fewer and I did not find a solution. Therefore, there probably isn't a single number of digits such that a solution $x$ exists.

### Python code

```
from math import *
n = 64
N = ceil(n*log10(2))
print(N)

K = floor(10**N / 2**n)
print(K)
print("")

for k in range(1,K+1):
    reducion_term = k*2**64
    string = str(reducion_term)
    test = True
    for i in range(N):
        y_i = int(string[i])
        y_20_i = int(string[19-i])
        condition = ((y_i + y_20_i) % 10) in [0,9,8]
        print(k,i,condition)
        if condition == False:
            test = False
            break
    if test == True:
        print("Maybe possible for k =", k)
```

This code did not find any value $k$ such that \eqref{eq1} could have a solution.
Therefore, no solution to \eqref{eq1} exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm struggling to understand your equation $(2)$: The RHS is the result of `actual_reverse` but what is the LHS supposed to be? To me it looks like it's $x+k \cdot 2^{64}$ instead of $\text{reverse_digits}(x)+k \cdot 2^{64}$ (which would follow from $(1)$)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However, we also assumed in the beginning that $x = \text{reverse_digits}(x)$. So, equation $(2)$ follows from $(1)$ together with the initial assumption on $x$.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification! Could you please also tell me how you derived $y_{20} + y_1 = k_1 \mod 10$ with $k_1 \in \{0,9,8\}$ from $x_{20} + y_{20} + j_{20} + y_1 + j_1 = x_{20} \mod 10$? I don't understand that step.

Comment: First subtract $x_{20}$ from both sides. Then subtract $j_1 + j_{20}$ from both sides. We know that $j_1, j_{20} \in \{ 0,1 \}$, hence $-(j_1 + j_{20}) \bmod 10 \in \{ 0,9,8 \}$. Define $k_1 = -(j_1 + j_{20})$.